# Passing permissions to Facebook Graph API using Postman

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, postman

How can I access anything more than name, pictures, that require permissions in Postman?

I have this code  `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?fields=name,birthday&access_token=[my access token]` but it only shows the name and id fields

It works in FB graph API but how can I do it in Postman

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Answer (score 0):

That call works fine for me:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cbirthday&access_token=my_token

using postman and curl (as Facebook's graph API console says in the `get code` button under the form).

I'd make sure that your token is really the same in both scenarios and that the fields you request are allowed there.

Comment: I realized the problem is the access token, how can get two kinds of access tokens? 
One that includes birthdays, emails etc.. and one that only allows, name, id and photo ? 

I'm using Titanium Appcelerator

Comment: No idea about this Titanium Appcelerator, but in the graph api you can create different user tokens and application tokens specifying all the different permissions.

So you can generate the token from the Graph Console and then copy it to your code, If you need to generate it dynamically then you'll need to check how to do that in the fb library of your choice.